# ¿Cómo modificar el valor de un elemento DIV varias veces sin recargar la página?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax

buenas tardes.
Quiero hacer una validación en vivo de usuario disponible. Para esto estoy generando una consulta con PHP con los usuarios existentes y cargandolos a un JSON[]. posterior el JSON lo asigno a un array en JS y comparo el valor del elemento INPUT con los registros en el array. El problema se genera al momento de mostrar en pantalla un mensaje de ¨usuario disponible¨ o ¨elige otro usuario¨, ya que si lo hace pero solo una vez, aun cuando la validacion la realiza cada vez que cambio los valores del input :(.

```
 $('#correo').focusout(function(){
   if($('#correo').val() != ""){
       var valores = $('#correo').val();
       var n = arrayGeneral.length, i = 0, bandera = false;
       $('#resultadoConsulta').html('<img src = "../includes/img/cargando.gif" width = "25px" heigh= "25px"> Verificando').fadeOut(1000);
       while(n > i){
           if(arrayGeneral[i].email == valores){      
               console.log("existe");
               bandera = true;
               break;
           }
           i++;
       }
       if(bandera == true){
           console.log("si");
           $('#resultadoConsulta').html("Usuario existe en Magento");
       }else{
           console.log("no");
           $('#resultadoConsulta').html("Usuario no existe en magento   ");
       }
   } 
});
```

Comment: Hola podrías de favor incluír el código fuente que te está creando problemas, y de preferencia también tu código HTML. Gracias

Comment: Por supuesto y lamento abusar de su ayuda, pero no encuentro la opción para agregar fragmentos de código. ¿puedo anexar un enlace como este -> https://paste.ofcode.org/BPubfrYcRSiejib6zfxQ4G (que es el JS) y sobre HTML el unico elemento que debe de cambiar es el siguiente: 
<div id="resultadoConsulta"></div>

Comment: En editar sobre las opciones de edición de texto, puedes agregar un fragmento de código la imagen corresponde a una hoja con dos signos de mas menos  `<>` Y ahí puedes incluír código HTML, JS y CSS

Comment: listo, gracias por la pasciencia.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que pasa es que en la parte de:

```
$('#resultadoConsulta').html('<img src = "../includes/img/cargando.gif" width = "25px" heigh= "25px"> Verificando').fadeOut(1000);
```

El `FadeOut()` Le agrega al contenedor que usas para mostrar el mensaje, el atributo `display:none`

lo único que debes hacer es agregarle un `show()`, aca abajo te dejo un ejemplo:

```
var arrayGeneral = [
                {email: 'correo@hotmail.com'},
                {email: 'correo2@hotmail.com'},
                {email: 'correo3@hotmail.com'}
            ];          
            $('#correo').focusout(function(){
                $('#resultadoConsulta').show();     
                if($('#correo').val() != ""){
                    var valores = $('#correo').val();
                    var n = arrayGeneral.length, i = 0, bandera = false;
                    $('#resultadoConsulta').html('<img src = "../includes/img/cargando.gif" width = "25px" heigh= "25px"> Verificando').fadeOut(1000);
                    while(n > i){
                        if(arrayGeneral[i].email == valores){      
                        console.log("existe");
                        bandera = true;
                        break;
                        }
                        i++;
                    }
                    if(bandera == true){
                        console.log("si");
                        $('#resultadoConsulta').html("Usuario existe en Magento");
                    }else{
                        console.log("no");
                        $('#resultadoConsulta').html("Usuario no existe en Magento");
                    }
                } 
            });
```

Espero que te sirva.